How to resolve 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied error in iis docker container?
I have hosted a sample index.html site within an IIS Docker container on my Windows Server. I assigned the domain check.vault.info to the HTML site inside the Docker container. Additionally, I configured Application Request Routing (ARR) as a reverse proxy in my local IIS instance to redirect traffic from check.vault.info to the IIS Docker container.
While the setup has been completed successfully, accessing the check.vault.info domain results in the following error.
Error:
403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
Docker file i used:
# escape=`
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8

# Enable Web Management Service and configure for remote management
RUN powershell Install-WindowsFeature Web-Mgmt-Service; `
    New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\software\microsoft\WebManagement\Server -Name EnableRemoteManagement -Value 1 -Force; `
    Set-Service -Name wmsvc -StartupType automatic

RUN net user iisadmin Password1 /ADD
RUN net localgroup administrators iisadmin /ADD
RUN powershell c: mkdir volume



RUN powershell -Command $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; `
    dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-NetFxExtensibility45 /NoRestart; `
    dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45 /NoRestart; `
    dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:WAS-WindowsActivationService /NoRestart; `
    dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:WAS-ProcessModel /NoRestart; `
    dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:WAS-ConfigurationAPI /NoRestart; `
    dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:WCF-HTTP-Activation45 /NoRestart

RUN powershell -NoProfile -Command Remove-Item -Recurse C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*


WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot


COPY . /inetpub/wwwroot


RUN Set-Service -Name 'w3svc' -Status Running -StartupType Automatic
RUN powershell -NoProfile -Command Start-Service w3svc


EXPOSE 443

ARR reverse proxy Web config file: point this domain "check.vault.info" to "192.168.2.12" this IIS container ip
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
                    <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="^http(s)?://192.168.2.12/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="http{R:1}://check.vault.info/{R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://192.168.2.12/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>                                          

Interestingly, I followed the same steps on a local machine IIS setup, and it worked without any issues. Anybody know how resolve this issue i faced ?

You do not have permission What security principals do have permission? Basic info there.

You have to reveal the exact settings from Dockerfile and applicationHost.config instead of your own words (which can miss quite a few details). Besides, enable IIS remote management if needed, so that you know you didn’t configure the wrong settings, https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/remote-management-of-containerized-iis-instances-on-windows-server-core-f6864c74917f

I have attached the docker file that I used to verify the above file and do you have any solution to solve this problem? @LexLi

It remains impossible to help because "I assigned the domain check.vault.info to the HTML site inside the Docker container" isn't reflected in the Dockerfile you shared. You didn't reveal any ARR setting either. You will have to share such if seriously looking for a solution here, or you'd better hire a local professional to take a look at your configuration which is usually quicker.

Sorry for the inconvenience I've attached ARR reverse proxy web config file above the post can you please check that ?  @LexLi
